# Polycarb or Polystyrene for vacuum molding?

Tags: headlight

I am working on making some projector headlights for my car. I would like to vacuum mold some plastic for the external cover to protect the lenses and housing from rocks and debris.

I have made a little box that I can lay my headlight into and vacuum the plastic with, but which type of plastic should I use? I have seen videos online on people using polystyrene to do this type of thing, but I am partial to polycarb because of it's strength.

Will polycarb be a good plastic to use to make a cover for my headlight - can I put it in my oven then vacuum it just like polystyrene? Or would it be better just to use the styrene for my molding?

Answer (score 1):

You’re better with either Lexan or polycarbonate. Polystyrene is too brittle. You need something that will resist UV and day to day weather.

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE. Try to add some references or sources to your answer to improve its quality.