# What's an effective way to protect headlight lenses from fading?

Tags: headlight, lights

I just ordered a pair of rather expensive LED headlights for my Jeep (KC Gravity Pro).

These have a polycarb protective "lens" which means that it will eventually fade, turn yellow, get chipped by rocks, etc.

Is there a protective film available that I could put over the headlights and change out every couple years?  What about 3M clear bra spray (or whatever it's called)?

This might be a really weird question, but I'm pretty particular about my lights, and after dropping $600 on headlights I would like to keep them performing well and looking good for hopefully the lifetime of the car.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean an entire headlamp unit, or just LED bulbs? A polycarb lens is way more prone to scratches than glass, that's right. A protective film is rather hard to apply though, because your headlights are somewhat spherical. It has to be an elastic film then. In your case, a grill wouldn't be a bad idea, it'd even enhance aesthetics. :p

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question or something very similar has been ask/answered before. I'm on my phine, so cannot search readily for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polycarb or Polystyrene for vacuum molding?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/polycarb-or-polystyrene-for-vacuum-molding)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 this is a different question.  I did ask that old one a long time ago when I was making some HID projectors, but this time I bought some pre made units that I would like to protect.

Comment: @thIngan, I'm voting that this is a different question because the duplicate isn't the same and has no quality answers.

Comment: I'm actually talking about these threads: [Sealing Headlights](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/32293/4152), [Cleaning Headlights](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/21684/4152), and [Polishing Headlights](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/11882/4152). Your headlights are brand new. While they don't need polished, if you treated them as if *they'd just been polished*, you'd get the same protection factor.

Answer (score 2):

UV rays are said to be one of the reason of headlights fading, also if you drive through deserts or dusty areas where sand particles impact on car and headlights can cause fading. One of the solution is to use UV Resistant clear coat on headlights its can be available in the market. One time application can last for months.

For deserts and sandy areas where you drive in speed you can put on glass coating on lights to prevent lights from fading.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of companies selling headlight film - mostly pre-cut to size for OEM.  3M, WeatherTech, Lamin-X.  Some wax companies like Meguiar sell fluids that theoretically leave a UV protective layer behind after they clean the lens.